# How to render responsive a Ext.form.TextArea

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I need some help about a form with a textarea field.

My problem.

I have a simple Ext.window in which I have put an Ext.FormPanel. In this Ext.FormPanel I have put an Ext.form.FieldSet in which I have put some fields. One of these field is a textarea (Ext.form.TextArea),
Now, my objective is to render responsive this textarea when I resize the Ext.window.

It is possible to obtain this behavior?

This is my current code:

Window in which reside the Ext.FormPanel

```
var    win = new Ext.Window({
    id:'winTest',
    layout:'fit',
    modal:true,
    title:'Title',
    width:590,
    height:300,
    closeAction:'close',
    plain: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    items:[form],
    listeners: {
        'beforeclose': function (p) {
        }
    }
});
```

Ext.FormPanel in which reside the Ext.form.FieldSet

```
var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
    id:'FormTest',
    layout : 'form',
    width:510,
    labelAlign: 'right',
    labelWidth: 120,
    autoScroll:true,
    bodyStyle:'padding:2px;background-color:#E9EFF8;',
    monitorValid:true,
    waitMsgTarget: true,
    border: true,
    bodyBorder: true,
    trackResetOnLoad:true,
    items: [fieldset]
});
```

Fieldset in which I have put some fileds

```
var fieldset = Ext.form.FieldSet({
    id:'fsTest',
    autoHeight: true,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items:[.....,textarea]
    //boxMaxWidth:450
    //border:true    
})
```

Textarea putted in the fieldset (to shorted, I have reported only the textarea)

```
var textarea = new Ext.form.TextArea({
    id:'textareaTest',
    name:'TextArea',
    fieldLabel:'Insert',
    hidden:false,
    width:310,
    height:60,
    maxLength:500,
    allowBlank: true
});
```

Thanks for any precious help.

Lorenzo.

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this:-

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
    id: 'winTest',
    layout: 'vbox',
    modal: true,
    title: 'Title',
    width: 590,
    height: 300,
    closeAction: 'close',
    plain: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        id: 'FormTest',
        flex: 1,
        layout: 'vbox',
        width: 510,
        labelAlign: 'right',
        labelWidth: 120,
        autoScroll: true,
        bodyStyle: 'padding:2px;background-color:#E9EFF8;',
        monitorValid: true,
        waitMsgTarget: true,
        border: true,
        bodyBorder: true,
        trackResetOnLoad: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            id: 'fsTest',
            //autoHeight: true,
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'vbox',
            //defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'textarea',
                    flex: 1,
                    id: 'textareaTest',
                    name: 'TextArea',
                    fieldLabel: 'Insert',
                    hidden: false,
                    width: 310,
                    //height: 60,
                    maxLength: 500,
                    allowBlank: true
                }]
                //boxMaxWidth:450
                //border:true
        }]
    }]
}).show();
```

Please have a look at this [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fot)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19472241)

Comment: Thanks for the info and support, I added code snippet.